# What is the derivative of a skew symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, skew-symmetric-matrices

I'm trying to work out some Jacobians and I ran across a problem. If I have a function of a vector making it a skew symmetric matrix, like below, what is the derivative $f'$?

$$ f(\boldsymbol{\omega}) = \lfloor \boldsymbol{\omega} \, \times \rfloor =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\omega_3 & \omega_2 \\
\omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1 \\
-\omega_2 & \omega_1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
$$

Comment: Derivatives are usually something you have for a function depending on a single parameter. Perhaps you want the partial derivatives or the differential of the function? That the function is matrix valued is probably the least complication; at the end of the day, the differentiation will occur entrywise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $M_{33}$ (the set of $3 \times 3$ matrices. Its three partial derivatives are 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega_1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}  
  0  & 0 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & -1 \\
  0  & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega_2} = 
\begin{bmatrix}  
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  0  & 0 & 0 \\
  -1  & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega_3} = 
\begin{bmatrix}  
  0  & -1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} .
$$

I suppose that I could treat $M_{33}$ as $\mathbb R^9$, and write out a $9 \times 3$ matrix, but would that really be any better?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose I was just hoping for some kind of identity with the skew operator.

Comment: Well, maybe a higher-level observation will help: the function $f$ is linear; that means that it is its own derivative. More exactly, $f'(\omega)$ is a constant (transformation-valued) function, whose value at any location $\omega_0$ is just $f(\omega_0)$. Is that more what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Employing the [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions) alternating tensor $\varepsilon$, your function can be written as
$$f = \,-\varepsilon\cdot\omega$$
whose derivative is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial \omega} &= \,-\varepsilon\cdot\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \omega} \cr
  &= \,-\varepsilon\cdot I \cr
  &= \,-\varepsilon \cr
}$$